# Batch line to print a file line by line

Tags: windows, batch

I'd like to write simple `Windows batch` line - a loop that iterate through a file line by line and for each line just prints that line. Here i what a have:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %f in ("del.txt") do echo %f
```

But that outputs:

```
C:\Users\Darek\test2>echo f1.txt
f1.txt

C:\Users\Darek\test2>echo f3.txt
f3.txt
```

while i'd rather expected just:

```
f1.txt
f3.txt
```

Why does it prints also the C`:\Users\Darek\test2>echo ...` for each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't disable echo of commands.

Put as the first line of your script

```
@echo off
```

(`@` before command is to not echo this command itself.)

Comment: Ok, got it, but now i have: `for /F "tokens=*" %f in (del.txt) do if EXIST FolderA\%lf @echo "%f - OK"` and i get `C:\Users\Darek\test2>echo ...` although the echo is disabled!

Comment: First line of your batch file: `@echo off`. Second line: your command `for /F "tokens=*" %%f in (del.txt) do if EXIST FolderA\%lf echo "%%f - OK"`.